# Having an Object return something other than it's whole self in Javascript

Tags: javascript

A piece of code I'm working on at the moment would benefit, potentially more from a semantic point of view, from the ability to have a call to 'just an object' return something other than the whole object. This may sound confusing so I shall elaborate with code.
If I had an Object constructor 'rectangle' defined as:

```
function Rectangle(side1, side2) {
    this.area = side1 * side2;    
}
```

What I'd then like to be able to do is call an instance of that object and then get a return value for it like so:

```
var foo = new Rectangle(1, 2);
return foo;
```

As it stands the return value will be something like a key:value pair. However, what I want is the return value to be something like "Hi Dave". I have read through various documentations on the Internet and have failed to find anything suitable.

Whilst I'm aware I could assign a property name to the "Hi Dave" statement and call that instead; for my application that does not make semantic sense. I am also aware that 'this' is not a variable and thus I can't just assign to that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Made an adjustment over what I want returned to avoid confusion.

Comment: You want you object to function like a function?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean please? I would like the thing that I have defined to maintain the properties such as area but return upon just calling the instance name, a value other than one describing the object.

Comment: "I want is the return value to be something like "I am a rectangle"" how would you use this value? For example if you want your object to be pretty printable you could set `Rectangle.prototype.toString = function(){return 'Ama rectangle'}`

Comment: The use case would be I have an object with some methods and properties but who for semantic reasons would return an arbitrary value of my choosing when the object instance is called.

Comment: You could return another *object* when function was called as a constructor. Even a `String`. For example `function Rectangle(a, b){ var rectangle = new String('Rectanlge'); rectangle.area = a*b; return rectangle}` But you could doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I think your final statement, paraphrased sums this up. Just because I could maybe do this, doesn't mean I should. I will stick to calling an additional method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest you can come to this is to override the `.prototype.valueOf` and `.prototype.toString` methods. This doesn't give you exactly what you wanted, which is being able to get a different *return* value, but, it will give you the desired value when used with strings.

```
class StringRectangle {
  constructor(val1, val2) {
    this.area = val1 * val2;

    this.__proto__.valueOf = () => 'My area is: ' + this.area;
    this.__proto__.toString = () => 'My area is: ' + this.area;
  }
}

const stringRect = new StringRectangle(2, 3);

// This is where the above fails for what you want
stringRect; // StringRectangle {area: 6}

// But, maybe these are good enough, since you're displaying strings?

// Uses valueOf
'My area is: ' + stringRect + '!'; // My area is: 6!
// Uses toString
`My area is: ${stringRect}!` // My area is: 6!
```

Looking further into your ideal solution, I don't think there is any way to do it cross browser, if at all. The value of references is stored at the machine level. Ex: what does `console.log` actually do? I have no idea without looking into the V8 code:

```
console.log(console.log); // function log() { [native code] }
```

It's that native code bit that's the limiting part here. If you want to delve into the native code, [start here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/7438304229b57a88f0b9857922f806af32718a80/src/inspector/v8-console-message.cc#L25) for the V8 console.log.

Thanks for the learning here; haven't delved this much into prototypes in a while.

Comment: `My area is: ${stringRect}!` logs `"My area is: [object Object]!"`

Comment: @guest271314 :( that's what I get for assuming strings are strings :(

Comment: @guest271314 actually, I had forgotten while testing that I had tried out `toString` as well. Seems string concatenation uses `valueOf` but template strings use `toString`

Comment: Whilst not exactly what I was looking for, this is actually pretty interesting and has provided me a direction to peek into in terms of achieving my goal. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `static` method on the `class`

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(side1, side2) {
    this.area = side1 * side2;    
  }
  static whoAmI() {return "I am a rectangle"}
}

var foo = new Rectangle(1, 2);
Rectangle.whoAmI();
```

Comment: For semantic reasoning, I wish to avoid calling additional methods to achieve my goal. I would rather simply call `foo` and get `'I am a rectangle'` with `foo.area` still returning 2 in your instance.

Comment: @DeanBrunt Are you trying to define `foo` as two separate values?

Comment: Not sure this is what OP wants. I *think* they want to basically change the implicit return value of the object, for a reason unknown.

Comment: I suppose when you put it like that I am... Which is daft. I get a strong feeling what I am asking for is not possible and I should settle with defining another method to return what I desire.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I believe you get what I am going for, but I now get the impression this was a fool's errand.

Comment: @DeanBrunt What is the purpose for presumptive requirement as described at Question?

Comment: It was for what in my mind was to be a very semantic piece of code, but due to sensibility and limitations should not be so much so.

Comment: @DeanBrunt it is but I'm working on it - give me like 30 min

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Curious what you are composing. How can a variable have two different values at the same time? `enum`, `getter`?  Where is value `return`ed from? What is purpose for requirement?

Comment: @guest271314 see below; I was hoping I could find something on the prototype that might be able to handle this, but I don't think such capability exists since as far as I can tell the underlying value access is kept in machine code only.